# Скрыть полосу прокрутки в QWebEngineView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

В документации имеется `QWebEngineSettings::ShowScrollBars` [ссылка](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#WebAttribute-enum), не совсем понял как задать параметр для этого атрибута, использую ***Python***.

На данный код никак не реагирует.

```
self.web = QWebEngineView()
self.web.settings().ShowScrollBars = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалите полосу прокрутки, ShowScrollBars, добавьте для 5.10
    loader.page().settings().setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.ShowScrollBars, False)

Вот пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

loader = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
loader.setZoomFactor(1)

# Удалите полосу прокрутки, ShowScrollBars, добавьте для 5.10 
loader.page().settings().setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.ShowScrollBars, False)

loader.page().pdfPrintingFinished.connect(
    lambda *args: print('finished:', args))

loader.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'))


def emit_pdf(finished):
    loader.show()
    #loader.page().printToPdf("test123.pdf")

loader.loadFinished.connect(emit_pdf)

app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо)